# Save image to disk from database with same size & quality as the original image

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to save images to a MSSQL database table which has the column type set to image, the purpose of my application is to save user uploaded images to the database and later-on users can retrieve those images from the database and if required save to disk.

I have already writted the below code to successfully achieve this task, however when I save an image to disk which is retrieved from the database, the file size seems to be lower than the original size.

*This naturally means the quality of the image has been reduced while saving or I am not retrieving the image properly.*

**This code is used to retrieve the image from the database.**

```
    Public Function __IMAGE_FROM_STREAM(ByVal img As Object) As Image
    __IMAGE_FROM_STREAM = Nothing
    If Not IsDBNull(img) Then
        Using mStream As New MemoryStream(img, 0, img.Length)
            mStream.Write(img, 0, img.Length)
            __IMAGE_FROM_STREAM = Image.FromStream(mStream, True)
        End Using
    End If
    Return __IMAGE_FROM_STREAM
End Function
```

**This code is used to save the passed in image to the database.**

```
    Public Function __IMAGE_TO_STREAM(ByVal image As Image) As Byte()
    __IMAGE_TO_STREAM = Nothing
    If Not image Is Nothing Then
        Using mStream As New MemoryStream
            Dim bm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(image)
            bm.Save(mStream, image.RawFormat)
            __IMAGE_TO_STREAM = mStream.GetBuffer
        End Using
    End If
    Return __IMAGE_TO_STREAM
End Function
```

**This code is used to save the retrieved image into the disk.**

```
    sfdExportImage.FileName = "export_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("d").Replace("/", "") & "_" & sender.Tag
    If sfdExportImage.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim fileName As String = sfdExportImage.FileName
        Dim expImage As Image = flpImageContainer.Controls("flpWrap_" & sender.Tag).Controls(0).BackgroundImage
        Try
            If expImage IsNot Nothing Then
                expImage.Save(fileName)
                MessageBox.Show("File exported successfully to " & fileName, __COMPANYNAME, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            __WRITELOG(ex)
        End Try
    End If
```

I have looked this problem up but no similar questions regarding this, am I missing any encoding parameters, I haven't worked with images & their classes alot so your feedback is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The `image` data type in SQL Server has been obsolete for well over a decade and the documentation would have told you that you should be using `varbinary` for saving any binary data.

Comment: I am still using MSSQL2008R2 will update the column types, however this isn't the cause of the problem right?

Comment: No, hence the comment rather than answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of dodgy stuff going in that code. Here's what your methods ought to look like:

```
Public Function ImageFromDbData(data As Object) As Image
    If data Is DBNull.Value Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Using strm As New MemoryStream(DirectCast(data, Byte()))
        Return Image.FromStream(strm)
    End Using
End Function

Public Function ImageToDbData(img As Image) As Object
    If img Is Nothing Then
        Return DBNull.Value
    End If

    Using strm As New MemoryStream
        img.Save(strm, img.RawFormat)

        Return strm.ToArray()
    End Using
End Function
```

They will go directly to and from a database value, i.e. `DBNull.Value` or a `Byte` array. There's no `Stream` at eaither end so your naming is wrong. There's also no point creating a `Bitmap` from an `Image` to save when you can just `Save` the `Image`. If you want to save the data from the database to a file then there's no point creating an `Image` object and saving that. Just call `File.WriteAllBytes` to save the `Byte` array directly.

Comment: So what is it that causes the image size to be reduced in my code.

Comment: With regard to your comment on File.WriteAllBytes, the reason I did it this way because when the user wish to save the image to disk the application shows the image in picturebox, so because of it I just used the BackgroundImage property of picturebox to do the exporting to the disk. So basically the image first comes from the database to picturebox -> then user can click to export to disk.

Comment: There's no point converting an `Image` to a `Byte` array if you have the `Byte` array that the `Image` was created from in the first place. Always use a single source of truth if you can.